# Frechet derivative of a function on matrix-valued $L^2$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, frechet-derivative

$\newcommand{\tr}{\text{Tr}}$
Let us denote $L^2(X, \mathbb C^{n \times n})$ be the space of matrix-valued $L^2$ functions. That is, if $f \in L^2(X, \mathbb C^{n \times n})$, each entry of $f$ is an $L^2$ function, i.e., $f_{ij} \in L^2(X, \mathbb C)$ for $i,j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$. Suppose we have a fixed $g \in L^2(X, \mathbb C^{n \times n})$, we define a function $F: L^2(X, \mathbb C^{n \times n}) \to \mathbb R$ by
$$ f \mapsto \text{Tr}(f^*g) \mapsto  \left( \int|\text{Tr}(f^*g))|^2 dx \right).$$

Is $F$ Frechet differentiable? I did following computation
\begin{align*}
F(f+h) - F(f) &= \int \tr(g^*(f+h)) \tr((f+h)^*g) - \int \tr(g^*f)\tr(f^*g) \\
&=\int \tr(g^* h)\tr(f^*g) + \int\tr(g^*h)\tr(h^*g) + \int \tr(g^*f)\tr(h^*g).
\end{align*}
Now letting $h \to 0$ in $L^2$, I am not sure the quotient
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\|h\|_{L^2} \to 0} \frac{|F(f+h) - F(f)|}{\|h\|_{L^2}}
\end{align*}
converges to something.

Comment: Try scalar valued functions first with $g=1$.

Comment: @copper.hat: With $g=1$, is it that $F$ just a linear functional over $L^2(X)$? So in this case, does it mean $DF(f)[h] = \int h dx$?

Comment: There is a square of modulus up there...

Comment: @copper.hat: I see, thanks. In that case, $F(f) = \|f\|_{L^2}^2$. Then $F(f+h) - F(h) = \langle f, h \rangle + \langle h, f \rangle + \langle h, h \rangle$. I think $\frac{ \langle h, h \rangle }{\|h\|_{L^2} }\to 0 $ as $\|h\|_{L^2} \to 0$. Then is it true $DF(f)[h] = \int f^* h dx + \int h^* f dx$. This should define a bounded linear functional on $L^2$ and so it is Frechet differentiable?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not differentiable because of the complex part. If it was a real valued functional it would be. For the same reason that $z \mapsto |z|^2$ is not analytic.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks. Now I see the problem. So even if we define a functional by $g \mapsto \int g^* dx$ with $g \in L^2(X)$, this function will not be Frechet differentiable. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct, because it is not linear.